# Android ad placement in a listview

Tags: android, ads, android-custom-view, flurry

I want to place android ads within a listview, I read an article about doing it with admob

I instead opted to try and do it with Flurry's appcircle, with no luck.

I am still comparing ad networks but this is a feature I want to discuss, as subjective comparisons between ad networks won't be allowed here.

What ad SDKs will allow me to do this? does anyone have resources about custom placement of ads

Comment: You can use android admobs for displaying the ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to place ads with the `ListView` in your layout like below:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   android:orientation="vertical"
>   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
>   <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         ads:adUnitId="AD_UNIT_ID"
>         ads:adSize="BANNER"
>         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
>   <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
>   <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/no_hosts"/>
>  </LinearLayout>
> ```

Checkout this [Example](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/03/embedding-admob-ads-within-listview-on.html), it will help you.

Comment: thanks, I believe this is the article I read, but what if I wanted to use another network? there seem to be so many Android ad solutions, many of which tap into admob amongst other networks. I've heard pros and cons about admob

Comment: they don't seem to have easy access to their sdk, also how can I be sure that they allow me to place them in any view I want?

Comment: To get the sdk you need to send the request from the site then only you will be able to get it. I also found another free ads demo check out http://code.google.com/p/mocean-sdk-android/source/checkout. This might help you.

Answer (score 1):

At instance, Google admobs merely just give you a custom view that extends `View`. It is up to you to place it anywhere you wish.

If you want to place your ad inside a `ListView`, you just need to write your own adapter and add the ad in `getView()`.